# Can This Be Done Quicker?

Tags: c, performance

I've got a function that takes some data that was received over SPI via DMA. For speed when transmitting via SPI, three 10-bit pieces of data are packed into one 32-bit word (with two padding bits). Once received, I need to unpack it back into three 16-bit words (ten actual data bits, and six padding bits).

This function is called quite often, so any speed optimization would make a big improvement in overall execution time. It's running on a STMicro Cortex M3, using IAR EWARM 7.10 as a compiler, with optimization set to high, optimized for speed.

```
    /*******************************************************************************
    * Function Name  : Unpack
    * Description    : the previous adc sample has been
               DMA'd into an array
               unpack each 32 bit transfer into 3, 10bit samples
              ( low 16 spi word ) ( high 16 spi word )
              { p15 p14 ch1_9:0 ch2_9:0 ch3_9:0 } 32 bit packing

    * Input          : output buf 16 bit word (10 bit adc, right justified)
               input buf 32 bit data
               count in 32 bit input words

    * Output         : None.
    * Return         : None.
    *******************************************************************************/
    void Unpack( u16* pDest, u16* pSrc, u16 packed32_count)
    {
       u16 i;
       u32 n;
       u16 dest_index = 0;
       u16 src_index = 0;

       for ( i = 0; i < packed32_count ; i++ )
       {
          n = pSrc[src_index]; //get high 16
          n <<= 16;
          n |= pSrc[src_index+1]; //get low 16
          src_index+=2;

          pDest[dest_index+2] = n & 0x3ff;
          n >>= 10;
          pDest[dest_index+1] = n & 0x3ff;
          n >>= 10;
          pDest[dest_index] = n & 0x3ff;
          dest_index+=3;
       }
    }
```

Comment: you can increment `pSrc` instead of using `src_index`

Comment: Which operating system, which compiler (including its version), which compilation flags (including optimization flags), which target processor and system?

Comment: @mch I would have thought this would help, too, but using src_index was actually faster (by ~500nS). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The following code is not much but it probably is quicker than the code above. Also you can try compiling with optimization affecting speed.

```
void Unpack( u16* pDest, u32* pSrc, u16 packed32_count)
{
    int i;
    u32 val;

    for(i = 0; i < packed32_count; i++)
    {
        val = pSrc[i];
        pDest[2] = val & 0x3ff;
        pDest[1] = (val >> 10) & 0x3ff;
        pDest[0] = val >> 20;
        pDest += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: the indexes of `pDest` are wrong, they should start with `2` and end with `0`

Comment: @n3rd4n1: Much better! I got about a 35% reduction with this! Thanks!

Comment: @n3rd4n1: Actually, this doesn't seem to actually be working to correctly unpack the data. It looks right to me, though. An endian issue I'm missing?

Comment: @nobby this code doesn't switch the lower 2 bytes with the higher 2 bytes, which your code do.

Comment: @nobby what do you see regarding the unpacked data? probably the 32-bit packed data has its padding non-zero? if it is it can easily be corrected with `pDest[0] = (val >> 20) & 0x3ff;`.

Comment: @n3rd4n1: Yes, that was my first thought, but I added that and the result is the same.

Comment: oh @mch is right. why do you have to do the swapping anyway. i assumed you had a packed data of format in bits (MSbit first): `00ccccccccccbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaa`.

Comment: Just noticed my comment in the header is wrong. The bit order is the other way. Added the swap in, and am still seeing significant improvements. Thanks again to @mch and @n3rd4n1!

Answer (score 1):

this could be a little bit faster

```
void Unpack( u16* pDest, u16* pSrc, u16 packed32_count)
{
   u32 n;
   u16* pSrcEnd = pSrc + 2 * packed32_count;

   while (pSrc < pSrcEnd)
   {
      n = *pSrc++; //get high 16
      n <<= 16;
      n |= *pSrc++; //get low 16

      *pDest++ = (n>>20) & 0x3ff;
      *pDest++ = (n>>10) & 0x3ff;
      *pDest++ = n & 0x3ff;
   }
}
```

Comment: pSrcEnd should be declared as a pointer. Tried this, it's about 5% faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your processor is big endian (if not you can sort this out in the packing, making the packing/unpacking symetrical), you can load the data with something like:

```
n = ((u32*)pSrc)[src_index++];
```

Also it might be faster to use u32 indexes than u16. Using 16-bit if you have 32-bit registers is not efficient.

You can use `register`, but I suspect the optimiser will have done so already:

```
register u32 src_index;
```

But if this is used very often, you should really look at the generated assembly code (to check there is no inefficiency when using 16-bit variables for example).